# org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: The alias 'Criterion' is already mapped to the value 'com.xxx.domain.def.GameListExample$Criterion'

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I use mybatis generator to generate domain and mapper. It works well when I generate one table.

When I generate another table , the problem comes. It seems like the Criterion class in GameListExample and BetRecdExample conflicts, but it was generated by mybatis.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'betRecdMapper' defined in file 
[F:\IdeaProjects\game\target\classes\com\good\game\dao\def\BetRecdMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: 
Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: The alias 'Criterion' is already mapped to the value 'com.good.game.domain.def.GameListExample$Criterion'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same issue as https://github.com/mybatis/generator/issues/461

It's caused by a bug in mybatis-spring 2.0.1.
https://github.com/mybatis/spring/issues/362
Current workaround is to use mybatis-spring 2.0.0 or 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: That's it.  The mybatis-spring-boot-starter default version is 2.0.1. It works when I change the version to 2.0.0.